# Manjaro: "invalid or corrupted package:" without package name

Tags: manjaro

I am getting `invalid or corrupted package:` without package name when try to update packages. `pamac upgrade` in terminal gives the same result.

I tried `sudo pacman-key --refresh-keys`, `sudo pacman-mirrors -g --country Russia` - no success.

How to get name of that package?

Answer (score 1):

Clear cache helps
`pacman -Scc && pacman -Syyuu`